# How to set default series/style in charts?

Tags: graph, charts, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Working with charts in Ax2012 and i they work ok. But i want to change the type of graph it shows when it starts up, for example a "Spline"-chart, not the default "column"-chart.

This is what i have now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyR9v.png

This is what i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cIIO.png

Here's a bit of my basic code:

```
Graphics    graphics;
Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Client.Controls.ChartToolBar chartToolbarControl1;
#MACROLIB.ChartFx
;

chartToolbarControl1 = chartToolbarControlHostChart.control();
chartToolbarControl1.set_ChartControl(Chart.control());

graphics = new graphics();
graphics.ManagedHostToControl(Chart);

graphics.parmCreateType(#ct_cluster| #cT_tool);
Graphics.parmSeriesType(#line);

graphics.create();
```

After this code I load all the data and show the graph. This works, but I want it to start as a Spline graph. This can easily be done after load by using the chart control above the graph and just selecting the spline type, but I can't get the graph to load with this setting.

If i try using the Graphics.parmSeriesType(#line); (or #pie or someother)
I don't get an error in my code, however when I run it I get the error:

> Null could not be obtained.

I have tried with several of these macros, but they all yield the same error except if I use #series_point. I have also tried just inserting regular ints from 1-25 to see if this works, but they give me the same error.

Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: I don't know how it works in ax 2012 but in ax 4.0 changing the graph type is done directly on the ActiveX control, not the graphics object.


`myActiveXChartControl.Gallery(#PIE);` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into the `Graphics` class and the `ChartFX` macro and found how and where the column style is being set. To set up your own chart style and follow the current pattern in AX, try the following:

1. Find the `SeriesChartType` enum integer value by searching this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype.aspx (This list is in order, and is 0-based. Spline is enum value 4).
2. Create a macro for this value in `ChartFX` like `#DEFINE.SERIES_SPLINE(4)`. Three values like this (for Point, Bar, and Column) are already defined in the `ChartFX` macro.
3. Modify the `classDeclaration` of the `Graphics` class to add another macro: `#DEFINE.SeriesChartTypeEnum_Spline("Spline")`
4. Modify the `setChartType` method of the `Graphics` class. After the current `if` statements present in the method, add this:

   ```
   else if (seriesType == #SERIES_SPLINE)
   {
       newChartType = ClrInterop::parseClrEnum(#SeriesChartTypeEnum, #SeriesChartTypeEnum_Spline);
   }
   ```
5. Now you can go back to your original code sample, and in place of `Graphics.parmSeriesType(#line);`, put `Graphics.parmSeriesType(#SERIES_SPLINE);`

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears to me that the `SeriesChartType` enum integer value doesn't matter at all, and the only thing that matters is that when `ClrInterop::parseClrEnum` is called, the string value you pass as the second parameter is the name of the chart type you want ("Spline" for example).